# Black magic probe boundary scan

Tags: arduino, stm32, debugging, tools, development-tools

I have a simple question. Can [black magic probe](https://1bitsquared.com/collections/frontpage/products/black-magic-probe) be used to do boundary scan?

I couldn't find that it says explicitly that.

If not, what would be cheapest alternative to do that on STM32 (STM32F103) and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source for the Black Magic Probe firmware, it does not appear that it supports boundary scan.

GDB commands to the BMP all go through [`gdb_main_loop`](https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic/blob/master/src/gdb_main.c#L94), which contains commands for reading and writing memory and registers and for starting, stopping and resetting the target processor, as well as the extended `q` and `v` commands. `v` is primarily for writing to flash, while `q` provides some descriptions of the target, as well as the GDB `monitor` commands.

Since GDB itself does not have any support for JTAG boundary scans, it is these `monitor` commands that provide the best chance for support, since they are passed directly to the BMP. However, looking at [the supported list of commands](https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic/blob/master/src/command.c#L65), none of them relate to JTAG boundary scanning.

While proving a negative is difficult, I can see no mechanism for handling boundary scan on the Black Magic Probe.

The most popular open source debugging tool that supports boundary scanning is most likely OpenOCD. It [supports SVF scans](http://openocd.org/doc/html/Boundary-Scan-Commands.html), though I didn't see any way to control individual pins through OpenOCD commands. OpenOCD supports a [wide range of hardware JTAG adapters](http://openocd.org/doc-release/html/Debug-Adapter-Hardware.html), though it does not appear to document whether all of them support boundary scan. Since you're using an STM32, maybe try the ST-LINK/V2.

Comment: So, ST-LINK/V2 in combination with OpenOCD should be able to perform the boundary scan?

Comment: @ShP I'm not going to guarantee that, since I wasn't able to find any documentation explicitly stating support. However, it should be easy to try it and see.

Comment: Fair enough :-)